# VBA code for Separating Sentence

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to separate two or more sentences, and after every sentence there should be a separator ";".

For example: Fined $33.5 million by FINRA, SEC for Puerto Rico Funds ; consumption index rises to 1.63 in August

Thank you!
DeeK

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works I'm afraid. This place is not a code writing service.

Comment: You should post what you've tried along with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `split()` function for such tasks, see example below:

```
Sub test()
    Dim S$, x As Variant
    S = " Fined $33.5 million by FINRA, SEC for Puerto Rico Funds ; consumption index rises to 1.63 in August"
    For Each x In Split(S, ";")
        Debug.Print x
    Next x
End Sub
```

test:

[image]

Comment: HI Vasily, Thanks for the help. I would like to add that currently my data set is like your "output" that is multiple sentences without any separator. I'm trying to merge two sentences but there should be a ";" between two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Separating two sentences is no easy task because you can only guess where a sentences ends.
You cannot simply split the text into single sentences by assuming each "." ends a sentence:

```
Fined $33.5 million by FINRA, SEC for Puerto Rico Funds
```

contains a . but is not two sentences.

The one thing I would do is assume that sentences are separated by the combination ". ". Should work most of the times.

To actually do that in code check out the "Replace"-function.
It is roughly used like this:

```
Dim replaced As String
replaced = Replace("This is a test sentence. This is the second sentence.", ". ", " ; ")
```

Although that will not delete . at the end of the text. You can remove that with:

```
if right$(replaced,1)="." then 
    replaced=left$(replaced, len(replaced)-1)
end if
```

You can easily work out a more elaborated solution from here on.